# Multiple Background Images To Repeat on Y left and Y Right

Tags: image, css, background

I'm trying to get two images to repeat ( one shadow image on the right, the other on the left) in the background exactly like this site.

So far I am unable to get the CSS code correct:

http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Modest/

I examined the code for that site and have the shadow images I wish to use. I tried to duplicate the code that Elegant Themes is using on a WordPress site running Headway:

```
.right-shadow { background: #ffffff url(images/right-shadow.png) repeat-y top right; }
.left-shadow { background:url(images/left-shadow.png) repeat-y top left; }
```

But it did not work.

Then I tried:

```
body {background:#ffffff url(http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/right-shadow.png) repeat-y right top;}
```

This worked for the right shadow image - it appears correctly

Then I tried

```
body {background:#ffffff url(http://websitebuddha.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/left-shadow.png) repeat-y left top;}
```

This worked for the left shadow image - it appears correctly

Now when I tried and combine the code to display both shadow images along Y left and Y right as such:

```
body {background:#ffffff url(http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/right-shadow.png) repeat-y right top, url(http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/left-shadow.png) repeat-y left top;}
```

It does not work - both images do NOT appear

I also tried this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/right-shadow.png), (http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/left-shadow.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y right top, repeat-y left top;
}
```

This also does not work - both images do NOT appear

How can I get this to work exactly as it does with the Modest Theme by Elegant themes?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Multiple Backgrounds` for your solution.

The background property has been overhauled to allow for `multiple backgrounds in CSS3`.

**CSS**

```
body {
background: url(http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Modest/wp-content/themes/Modest/images/left-shadow.png) 0 0 repeat-y,  
 url(http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Modest/wp-content/themes/Modest/images/left-shadow.png)center right repeat-y;  
}
```

I hope this will help you :- http://tinkerbin.com/Iw4yJ1H3

Answer (score 0):

here's one way you could do it. Not using backgrounds as such. Although you could place the images as backgrounds on the divs or simply have them added as images within the divs. You could even do away with the divs and sinmply use images instead of the divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/6UEXc/

Hope that helps.